# F# List.item operator expr.[idx] used on object of indeterminate type

Tags: f#

I'm trying to learn F# and I'm following [this sample](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/files/analyzing-visualizing-data-f-sharp.pdf) (page 37, inside the `kmeans` function): since my code is in F# 4, I need to update the following to use `List.item` instead of `List.nth`:

```
let centroids =
    let rnd = System.Random()
    [ for i in 1 .. clusterCount ->
        List.nth data (rnd.Next(data.Length)) ]
```

Which becomes:

```
let centroids = 
    let random = System.Random()
    [for i in 1 .. clusterCount -> 
        data.[(random.Next(data.Length))]]
```

But I now get an error saying `The operator expr.[idx] has been used on object of indeterminate type... Consider adding further type constrains` on the last line. If I add the `(data:(float*float)list)` type constrain it goes away, but how can I keep the flexibility of having `data` as `'a list`and still use `List.item`?

Comment: Why not annotate with the generic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generic types as a type annotation:

```
(data : 'a list)
```

Or, if you don't want to name it:

```
(data : _ list)
```